# Adjust column width in Quick Edit or Datasheet View

Tags: datasheet, quick-edit

I am trying to find a way adjust the column widths/wrap text in the Quick Edit/Datasheet view in SharePoint 2013.

So far, I have only seen ways to adjust the widths in the standard view (using CSS), but these seem to not get applied to the Quick Edit or Datasheet view.

Answer (score 0):

use in your CSS:

```
.ms-spGrid-HeaderContentStyle div{
white-space: normal;
}
```

Already solved here:
[Column Width in Quick Edit or Datasheet View](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212141/column-width-in-quick-edit-or-datasheet-view)